# How to launch the Discoverability overlay programmatically when XCUI testing on iOS

Tags: ios, xcuitest, uikeycommand

The Discoverability overlay displays the available [`UIKeyCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand)s when a user connects a hardware keyboard to an iOS device.

A user launches the overlay by holding down the Command key.

XCUITests provide a high-level API to blackbox test your app, by allowing you to query the view hierarchy and perform actions upon those views.

For localization and screenshot purposes, I wish to be able to launch the Discoverability overlay from a `XCUITestCase`.

[image: Discverability overlay]

Unfortunately, [`XCUIKeyModifierFlags`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuikeymodifierflags?language=objc) is macOS only.

[`UIDevice.press`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuidevice.button) is only for on-device hardware buttons.

What am I missing?

**How do I launch the Discoverability overlay from an `XCUITestCase`?**

At a stretch, I can add something in the application code, but then how do I launch it from the application?